# Activate <div> based on User Agent

Tags: php, html, user-agent

I need to activate a "div" based on the user agent string. For example, (and this is my actual use for this,) A user with Firefox comes to my site. I want to tell them something along the lines of "Welcome Firefox User! Thank you for supporting Open Source Software, etc;".

That message is inside a Div. I would like to just show it for firefox users. It has to be compatible with most modern (mainstream) browsers. I am using PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Artur

Comment: What server-side technology are you working in? PHP?

Comment: Yep. It's on a self-hosted WordPress install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On server-side with PHP, you can inspect the user's browser string with the built-in $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variable. Then, based on its value, you can output a DIV.

Comment: How would I output a div? Like, code wise? (Javascript is fine. I have jQuery installed.

Comment: echo "<div>Hello world</div>";

Comment: Yes, but how would I define it's visibility based on the User Agent?

Comment: if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Firefox") !== FALSE) {
  echo "<div>hello world</div>"; 
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Firefox") !== FALSE) { ?>
  <div>Thanks for supporting Firefox!</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Not very reliable, though.  I answered just so I could do the conditional-drop-out-of-PHP thing, which I abhor.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the OS it's running on? Like, only for Mac Firefox?

Comment: Yep: if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Firefox") !== FALSE && strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Mac") !== FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use server side detection, but as you've not specified what language you are using, I can only suggest a frontend (javascript) method.

jQuery has a utility function `jQuery.browser()` which will return one of a number of "flags" based on the useragent string. Take a look at the docs at the link below for more information.

[jQuery.browser() @ jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser)